# How do I search for a string from table column in SQL Server using CHARINDEX function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a string in table column like below

```
1. "C-DERD,C-FDER,E-FDFE,E-DFE,C-DFERE"
2. "E-FDFE,C-DFEC,E-DFDFE,E-DE"
```

If I search for a string like "DE" then it will first check all the individual string that starts with 'C-' AS LIKE CONSTRAINT IN TABLE. If it is found, then it will return TRUE in separate column, in second case it is not found in 'C-' case then it will check in all individual string that start with 'E-' but it is same as searched string. With use of `CHARINDEX` function only.

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing lists as comma-delimited strings.

Comment: I don't see why you need charindex. You can just use `where columnName like '%DE%'`. Don't ask for answers using a specific method... this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead, describe the problem and the ultimate goal.

Answer (score 2):

As I mention in a comment, you should fix the data structure. Sometimes, though, we are stuck with other people's really bad designs and are not in a position to fix them.

One method is to split the string, although that is a bit painful.  In your case you could do:

```
select t.*,
       (case when str like '%CE-DE%' then 1
             when str like '%CE-[^,]DE%' then 1
             when str like '%CE-[^,][^,]DE%' then 1
             when str like '%CE-[^,][^,][^,]DE%' then 1
             else 0
        end) as flag
```

This looks for up to three intervening characters between the `-` and `DE`, which is sufficient for your examples.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff